# User Pool not registered

Tags: swift, aws-sdk

After loading all my AWS SDK into my project to implement the sign in process I am getting this error. all the files are well loaded.
is there anyone who know what I am probably missing??

Thanks for your help

```
2017-02-08 16:37:05.799 ClientService2[37948:950374] Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <ClientService2.ClientListTableViewController: 0x7fafb3e05040>.
2017-02-08 16:37:06.495 ClientService2[37948:950374] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UINavigationController: 0x7fafb4807a00>.
2017-02-08 16:37:07.288 ClientService2[37948:950374] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'User Pool not registered. The method `setupUserPoolWithId:cognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientId:cognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientSecret:region` has to be called once before accessing the shared instance.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d0fd4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010277121e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   ClientService2                      0x0000000101a213cb +[AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider sharedInstance] + 171
    3   ClientService2                      0x0000000101a03f65 _TFC14ClientService220SignInViewController18handleCustomSignInfT_T_ + 69
    4   ClientService2                      0x0000000101a04042 _TToFC14ClientService220SignInViewController18handleCustomSignInfT_T_ + 34
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001031358bc -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001032bbc38 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001032bbf51 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001032bae4d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001031a3545 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001031a4c33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001031519ab -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010393e72d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000103937463 __handleEventQueue + 4879
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102cb4761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102c9998c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102c98e76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102c98884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000107268a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000103133c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    20  ClientService2                      0x0000000101a20bbf main + 111
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010539168d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: I suspect User Pool not registered yet. Maybe you can fix this by caling method setupUserPoolWithId:cognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientId:cognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientSecret:region once before accessing the shared instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before creating an instance of the cognito user pool, you should register your User Pool with the information provided in the console. This information is the clientId, poolId and clientSecret. After this, you can create the user pool instance correctly.

For example, when the app starts, you should do the following:

```
let poolName = "poolName"

// You should update the region to be the one where you created the pool
let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.usWest2, credentialsProvider: nil)

let configuration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: "Client Id found in the console here", clientSecret: "Client secret found in the console here", poolId: "Pool Id here")

AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.register(with: serviceConfiguration, userPoolConfiguration: configuration, forKey: poolName)
```

Afterwards, you can get a reference to the user pool by doing the following:

```
let userPool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: poolName)
```

All the mentioned information can be found in the user pool console!